# django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for '/' not found. '/' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django, selenium, unit-testing, django-tests

I am trying to follow Python TDD O'Reilly.

I know the django version they've used is an old one, however, even after making all possible amends, I am getting this error.

My urls.py files:

superlist.urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from django.conf.urls import url


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('lists.urls')),
]
```

lists.urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('/', home_page)
]
```

lists.views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import (render, HttpResponse)
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
# Create your views here.

@api_view()
def home_page(request):
    return HttpResponse('Response')
```

lists.tests.py

```
from django.test import TestCase
from .views import home_page #


class HomePageTest(TestCase):
    def test_root_url_resolves_to_home_page_view(self):
        found = reverse('/') 
        self.assertEqual(found.func, home_page)
```

How could I solve this? I've tried to search about this for long, with no avail.

Answer (score 5):

The `reverse` function [is used like this (Django docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urlresolvers/):

```
 reverse(viewname, urlconf=None, args=None, kwargs=None, current_app=None)¶
```

"viewname can be a URL pattern name or the callable view object"

You are trying to refer to a view by using the URL path linked to it. What you actually need to do is add a URL pattern name to your `path` call, and refer to that instead. So you could use:

```
path('/', home_page, name='home')
```

And then

```
found = reverse('home')
```

Also, the `reverse` function returns the URL path linked to your view, not the actual view. So your `.assertEqual` test will still fail. You might find the examples of reverse resolution of URLs in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#examples) helpful.